# Is this memory leak from my program or the computer? How can I fix it?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, valgrind

I was practising my programming and memory allocation.When i execute without valgrind the program works and it does what it needs to do. Then i executed with valgrind to see if i had any memory leaks.This is what i got when executing with valgrind. Im kind of new and i cant find why do i have so many memory leaks or errors. The code is below. Thanks!!

[image]

```
 1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <stdlib.h>
  3 int* fun(int *l){
  4          int *k;
  5          k = (int *)malloc (4*sizeof(int));
  6          for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
  7              k[i] = 2*l[i];
  8              l[i] += 1;
  9          }
 10          return k;
 11          free(k);
 11 }
 12 int main(){
 13          int *s;
 14          int *t;
 15          s = (int *)malloc (4*sizeof(int));
 16          s[0] = 2; s[1] = -3; s[2] = 5; s[3] = 0;
 17          t = fun(s);
 18          for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
 19              printf(" %d   %d\n", s[i], t[i]);
 20          }
 21          free(s);
 22          free(t);
 23          return 0;
 24 }
```

Comment: The statement `free(k)` is unreachable because of the return statement before it.

Comment: i also get memory leaks if i put free(k) before the return of if i remove the free(k)

Comment: Please don't post images: rather copy/paste the data as text into the question.  Please do not post the line numbers.  For use to reproduce the problem, we have to edit every line to remove the line number

Comment: OT: regarding: `k = (int *)malloc (4*sizeof(int));`  1) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code and is error prone.  2) always check (!=NULL) the the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror( "your error message");` to properly output both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.

Comment: in function: `fun()` regarding: `free(k);`  this statement is never executed and you do not want to execute it.  Suggest removing that statement.

Comment: OT: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 4.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest use a `enum` statement or `#define` statement to give that 'magic' number a meaningful name then use that meaningful name throughout the code.

Comment: regarding the valgrind message: *definitely lost: 3,854 bytes in 56 blocks*  This message did not originate from the program you posted.  Please post the code that resulted in the valgrind messages.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the posted code did not cause the generation of the valgrind error messages

Comment: yes it comes from that code . well not exactly ,i get the same leaks at every program i do, (including that one), but at the time i posted the question i didnt know that. even if my program only does printf("hello\n") and nothing else i still get the same leaks. similar to what happens to the guy who posted this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45527113/is-my-valgrind-installation-broken) .

Answer (score 1):

The `free` statement in your function `fun` is never executed because of the `return` statement just before it.

Also, you might consider to use `vector<int>` instead of `*k`, `*l`, `*s` and `*t`.

Example:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int> s;      
s[0]=1;
```

Comment: i still get leaks if i put it before the return

Comment: See my answer with new example

Comment: i think its the valgrind compiler that is somehow broken or its the computer because i get the exact same leak with a program that only does printf("hello\n");