# I think my valgrind installation is somehow broken

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, valgrind

with this simple code

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <stdlib.h>
  3 int main(){
  4     int n = 3;
  5     printf("%d \n", n);
  6     return 0;
  7 }
```

i get this leaks

[image]

I dont know how to fix this. I have already seen this post [Is my valgrind installation broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45527113/is-my-valgrind-installation-broken)  but i cant understand how to fix it. I have a MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/mX4NC.png

Comment: Could be a leak in a system library.  Add `--leak-check=full` and `--show-reachable=yes` to see exactly where these leaks are.

Comment: now that i know where the leaks are what should i do? how can i delete them ?

Comment: You can create a suppressions file with the system library leaks.  The man page for valgrind describes how to do this.

Comment: i canrt unterstand how to do it :(

Answer (score 0):

First run Valgrind with `--gen-suppressions=all` and the leak options already given in the comments. You may also want to use `--log-file=my.log` or something like that.

Then look at the output. You will see something like

```
{
   <insert_a_suppression_name_here>
   Memcheck:Leak
   [leak type]
   [callstack]
}
```

Copy this text to a file like "mysuppressions.supp", rename the `<insert_a_suppression_name_here>` line to be something meaningful and unique. The tricky bit is choosing which parts of the callstack to copy. If you copy too many lines then the suppression will only apply to your particular case. If you copy too few lines then the suppression will be too broad and you will risk getting false negatives. As a rule you don't want the suppression to contain any of your functions, just the system functions.

Lastly run Valgrind using your suppression file

```
valgrind --suppressions=mysuppressions.sup ./bru.exe
```

Comment: How many is too little and how many is too much? Right now i have 12 lines of the callstack wich all start with fun:

Comment: also, how can a know if the function is mine or is it a system function?